# Pairing bluetooth mouse with two system on same computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, opensuse, wireless-mouse

I have a Microsoft Mobile Memory Mouse 8000 paired to my notebook under Windows via Bluetooth. However I have a Linux installation as well (openSUSE 12.1) and I thought I could make that mouse work for both system, since both of them shares the same Bluetooth receiver. Also whenever I move the mouse while it's in Bluetooth mode, the system detect it's connection attempts, and asks for a pairing key.

Is there a way to do this with a Bluetooth device?—It would be awesome!

Comment: I think I did it, but I need to test it first.

Comment: Did it work? If yes, please submit an answer to your question.

Comment: Sadly, no. It required to pair the mouse each and every time.—The idea was to pair it under Linux, where it gives a pairing number to the device, (like 0000) and then pair it with Windows. Unfortunately this didn't keep it paired up in Linux.

Comment: @AdamL.S. I think the problem is the mouse thinks it is already paired because the Bluetooth MAC is the same. If you could spoof it in either one of the OSs so that it appears different, you'll be able to pair to both of them (if the mouse supports multiple devices) and use them quite seamlessly.

Comment: Wow, that was so long ago, I even forgot that mouse. (Or the question for that matter.) @deed01392 I had the same idea. And no, that mouse doesn't support multiple pairings. Instead, I wanted to spoof the system believing it already knows it.